# Cannot write to the Access Database

Tags: vb.net-2010

When I press the button I want Sname and SNo to be written to the database. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim ConnString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Documents and Settings\cerns1\Local Settings\Application Data\Temporary Projects\WindowsApplication1\testdb.accdb"
    Dim cnn As New OleDbConnection(ConnString)

    ' Create a new row. 
    Dim newStudentRow As testdbDataSet.StudentRow
    newStudentRow = Me.TestdbDataSet.Student.NewStudentRow()


    ' Save the new row to the database 
    Dim i As Integer = 2
    Dim SNo As Integer = 1
    Do While i > 1
        cnn.Open()
        'StudentTableAdapter.Insert("WOW", SNo)
        Me.TestdbDataSet.Student.Rows.Add(newStudentRow)
        Me.StudentTableAdapter.Update(Me.TestdbDataSet.Student)
        SNo = SNo + 1
        i = i + 1
        cnn.Close()
    Loop


End Sub
```

After executing, no information is added or changed in the Access database.

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Comment: Just a tip: this code will make your program crash. The loop goes as long as i is greater than 1, and you're adding 1 to i every time you iterate. Also opening and closing the connection over every iteration is bad, open it once and close it after the operation is done.

Comment: @Bill Gregg It will run without problems but does not save to the access database. When I open the database after it is still the same.

Comment: @Abbas okay, I will have to make that change. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I found that if I look in the debug folder the changes are saved there. What reason would cause them to save there and not on my regular database? And how can i get them to save the the one in my WindowsApplication1 Folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that if I look in the debug folder the changes are saved there. To change that I had to manually change the connection string to my WindowsApplication1 Folder.